# Segmentation fault when installing key value in hash table

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable

**EDIT: I have updated the init function(code updated) to use malloc and the segmentation fault is gone. However I get no output from the print table function now.
Further updated the code as per suggestions. It seems to work now.**

I've been following K&R (beginner in C) for C and tried writing a hashtable using their example in section 6.7 (with few modifications)

The code is below-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hashtable.h"

#define HASHSIZE 101


listptr * init_table()
{
    listptr *hashtab = (listptr *) calloc(HASHSIZE, sizeof(*hashtab));
    return hashtab;
}

unsigned hash (char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;

    for (hashval=0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;

    return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}

listptr lookup (listptr * hashtab, char *s)
{
    listptr np;

    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np!=NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)
            return np;
    return NULL;
}

listptr install(listptr * hashtab, char *name, char * defn)
{
    listptr np;

    unsigned hashval;

    if((np = lookup(hashtab, name)) == NULL) {
        np = (listptr) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np==NULL || (np->name = strdup(name))==NULL)
            return NULL;

        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    }
    else
    {
        free((void*) np->defn);
    }
    if ((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return np;
}

void printtable(listptr * table, int len)
{
    listptr p;
    int i =0;
    while (i < len) {
        if (table[i] != NULL) {
            for (p = table[i];p!=NULL;p=p->next) {
                printf("%s\t%s\n", p->name, p->defn);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

hashtable.h contains -

```
#ifndef HDR
#define HDR

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nlist *listptr;

typedef struct nlist {
    listptr next;
    char *name;
    char *defn;
} Hashtablebucket;

listptr * init_table();
listptr lookup(listptr *, char *);
listptr install (listptr *, char *, char *);
void printtable(listptr *, int );

#endif
```

In main.c I have -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hashtable.h"

int main()
{
    listptr * table = init_table();


    install(table, "key1", "value1");
    install(table, "key2", "value2");
    install(table, "key3", "value3");

    printtable(table, 101);

    return 0;
}
```

This results in a segmentation fault and I have no idea what could be wrong as the hashtable has 101 elements of space.

Would appreciate any help in debugging the problem...

EDIT: With the above code there is no output at all. Could someone please help with the debug?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not checked other parts, your `init_table` is wrong because it is returning an address of non-static local variables, which will become invalid on returning from the function, and the address is used later. `malloc()` from `stdlib.h` should be used to dynamically allocate memories.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? My K&R copies do not have the init_table function...

Comment: Thanks MikeCAT, I've updated the init_table function and now it no longer segfaults. But now there is no output. Could you please help with the rest of the code?

Comment: Since you found the reason for the segfault, you should post a new question for the new problem.

Comment: Olaf it is a related problem...

Comment: You must not cast the return value of malloc.

Comment: ... you're printing only 2 of the first slots

Comment: and using `malloc` is wrong, since you didn't initialize the table. Use calloc.

Comment: Antti Haapala - what would be the right approach in the init_table function? I get a segfault again when I increase it from 2 slots to 101

Comment: @g0d `malloc` does not initialize memory. The K&R code assumes the table is zero-initialized as is true for *objects of static storage duration*. That's why you need to use `calloc` (or set every pointer to null pointer manually). Also your allocation code did not allocate the table correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original K&R code assumes a global table. In your case you try to allocate it locally, but you cannot return a pointer to local variable (well, you can, but the behaviour is undefined). Instead you need to allocate the memory using `malloc`/or even better, `calloc` in this case:

```
listptr * init_table()
{
    listptr *table = calloc(HASHSIZE, sizeof *table);
    return table;
}
```

It would be preferable to make a *struct* for the hash table, so that you can have tables of different sizes:

```
struct hashtable {
    size_t n_slots;
    listptr *slots;
};

struct hashtable *init_table(size_t n_slots) {
    struct hashtable *tbl = malloc(sizeof *tbl);
    tbl->n_slots = n_slots;
    tbl->slots = calloc(n_slots, sizeof *(tbl->slots));
    return tbl;
}
```

---

For `hash` function, it is better to keep it so that it returns an `unsigned int` (or `size_t`!) always, and do the modulo outside that function. Also, `char` can be signed or unsigned; you'd most probably want to use `unsigned char`s.

I.e.

```
size_t hash (char *s)
{
    size_t hashval;

    for (hashval=0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        hashval = *(unsigned char*)s + 31 * hashval;

    return hashval;
}
```

and

```
hashval = hash(name) % tbl->n_slots;
```

Comment: I have taken up your suggestion of using a struct for the hash table itself for tables of different sizes. Do you recommend changing the other functions to accept struct hashtable as an argument or just pass tbl->slots to functions like install etc.?

Comment: Also how to modify the hash function to use the new n_slots?

Comment: @g0d *pointer* to `struct hashtable` as an argument, yes. As for `hash()`...